# There is a way to get file url from OneDrive app like Dropbox api (DBChooser)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, onedrive

The objective is to click on a button, open OneDrive app, select a file and return to myApp with url from the selected file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the OneDrive API web page](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdks.htm), a file picker you can use is the [UIDocumentPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html).

Set a delegate to respond to [`UIDocumentPickerDelegate/documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerDelegate/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIDocumentPickerDelegate/documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:) and you'll have your URL.

Comment: Just one more question! Im adding an option to UIDocumentMenuViewController with  "addOptionWithTitle: image: order:UIDocumentMenuOrderFirst handler:", the image i gave appears blue! I dont know why, do you already faced this problem??